# Trying to make character for UE4 - Need guidance

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, unreal-engine

I have made a knight character, and I want to give him a skeleton to throw him in UE4, though I have a few things making that less than simple. Mostly, I want to be as accurate to an existing skeleton as possible (the default UE4 skeleton) but importing that into Blender has some major issues. [image]

So I've started making my own skeleton as close to the UE4 one as I could, I've got UE4 on my other screen. I don't know about a couple of things. First, there's "twist bones" on the upper arm and upper leg, as well as a "root". I don't know how those should look, or if I even need the twist bones (I know I need the root).

I need to know:

What do I do for the root?

How can I mirror what I've done  to the other side?

Can I do without the twist bones?

Strangely I can't find much if anything for making armatures specifically for UE4, or without using Rigify, so maybe I'm just doing it wrong. I could use some guidance.

Here's the hierarchy I've got so far, it perfectly matches UE4.
[image]

And just for fun, here's what I'm trying to get animated. [image]
[image]

Help and advice greatly welcome and appreciated.

Comment: too broad, and also multiple questions, so not well suited for this site... try to break it down to smaller, focused questions, or try a different website, like blenderartists.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an Answer that actually works just right:

Export The UE4 mannequin.

Remove anything you dont want to use including MESH, IK bones, Twist bones.

Turn on snap and set it to verticies.
Then grab ends of bones that are in the wrong positions. Move them using the axis arrows onto the correct bones.
Save it for next time as it's own file

Next bring in your mesh. Scale appropriately for unreal
In object mode, select the skeleton. Press shift+C so that you scale from origin. Scale it to your mesh.

Turn on the mirror x and move bones as needed.

In object mode, select the mesh and skeleton and press CTRL+P
set them by weight when asked.

Go into weight mode and fix all the crazy stuff it will do for whatever reason.
Export to unreal.

In unreal make sure you dont choose a skeletal mesh during import.
Open the UE4 skeleton. Get to the rigging options and set it to the humanoid rig

On your skeleton do the same thing.

Go find whatever animation you want, right click on it. 
Select Animation re target asset, and in the process just choose your skeleton.

Skip all the rigging stuff in blender.
Where i was having problems was the weighting. I didnt realize when I would just parent the unreal skeleton to what was basically an unreal model with some clothes on it that i was choosing some CRAZY weights.
I was able to fix them fast by setting the weight tool to subtract, full power zero fall off and going through each bone and drawing over the whole model that WASNT obviously supposed to be connected.

I did over do it a bit, but the system is kind enough once it was all set up i could have UE open and blender, modify the weight and export. UE will process the changes and instantly show them in the animation window I had open.

(I had a beltbuckle attached to right pinky, left pinky attached to right ball, all sorts of pieces of the shirt attached to random parts of arms, the spine 1 was the whole torso and the rest of the spines connected to random parts of shit/buttons on shirt etc.

Now i am on to fixing the duster so it doesnt go through the characters legs and it's acting all funny around shoulders when character lifts arms...

I dont do anything to the Root. And the pelvis is in the right position/size.
just get it connected to the spine.
[image]

When you do export the FBX you need to go to the settings on left, click in the armature section and untick add leaf bones. Otherwise it adds extra ones to the fingers and such.

Inside unreal the skeleton will have 2 roots. There is a file somewhere supposedly that will fix the export of that. But the links I had to it were either dead or only worked on much older Blender versions.
I found you can click on the highest one in the skeleton mesh asset and right lick, disable from LOD 0 and below. It still shows on the list but isnt connected to anything any more and isnt used.

I put my empty rig FBX here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lq1SBXGq9485KXKbYENgI-sEMUeUCUGN

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I had my spine "backwards" and some things were off proportionally, having your rig for reference helped. I just threw in a mesh for retarget testing, and although the skeleton looks kinda weird in UE4, it works flawlessly on this at least. I'm so happy to have this now, hopefully I can work up the motivation to go back and do the other character I made. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently Working on this myself. 
If you find a good solution that works well I would appreciate you posting it for us.
As for your questions I can give you what I have found/know so far.

Using this: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/animation/100864-tutorial-how-to-make-ue4-mannequin-in-blender

explains how to fix that skeleton. Basically for re-targeting and such you dont need the twist or IK bones. Delete them.
Then you turn on the snap tool (magnet down at the bottom, and button next to it set it to vertices)
Then Press "t" if your tools arent open. Select "Options" and there is a Mirror on x axis option.

Then you'll notice every bone except the finger tips, and ball of foot has one side in the appropriate spot already. You will select the part that is in the WRONG spot (like the top of spine_01) and use the x,y,z arrows to move it. Just just mouse over Spine_02 base and it will highlight. When you have done it for all 3 axis it will be exactly connected to Spine_02
Just watch the clavicles, there is a spine piece there that is REALLY easy to get swapped with one of them because their rotations put them in funny spots....

now from there i have tried:
a. Riggifying, and using the new rig. This seems to always create a poorly matched rig that doesnt actually have any connections to 1/2 the mesh. And wont move in the UE engine
b. just selecting the mesh and skeleton and setting a parent, and selecting by weight when asked. 
This gives you none of the mesh moveable in blender But when exported into the engine will be able to select everything correctly when you hit the auto generate rig. Also under the skeleton mesh you can select a bone and move it all just how you would want.
Biggest issue here seems to be the physics asset. I end up with an EXPLOSION of blue circles. That dont scale right, wont let me edit them appropriately and of course would prevent anything from even considering moving right.

This video:
https://youtu.be/jiXwDxCZtOc
covers the blender rig into unreal. But I think some things have changed sense then. 
1. my Blender rig doesnt look the same
2. When i hit generate rig it doesnt look the same
3. the script fails to run to remove extra bones

And so on.
Basically I get the same problems in different ways from this tutorial.

Comment: I'll get to trying the "fixing skeleton" route again... it's seeming like the best option despite being quite complicated. I did find the video you linked, though I suffered the same issue of getting a different result from the video. The skeleton has additional bones from the video and the auto rig failed for me too, couldn't fix it. I'm just amazed how much issue I'm having and how little help there is, considering how important all of this is for video games. I would expect more resources or help to be out there.

Comment: https://youtu.be/i_imzw2PJcg You will see below that I gave an answer. This video is basically A time lapse version of what I did. I show you deleting the UE mesh, removing some of the bones, then how I lined them up. Then I loaded the file I was using to attempt the attachments/rigging, that's exactly how I ended up putting them together and then just modifying the weight. If you need me to show How I got the skeletons rigged or anything let me know...probably on that video comment and i'll make another for you. Hope I was helpful

Comment: For anyone following this, don't forget to delete the twist bones! He connects them in the video, which results in 4 bones per leg. I was about to ask how to get a more accurate skeleton, but then I remembered he said to delete those. Now my skeleton looks pretty good.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how you did the root bone as well as the pelvis? I just want to make sure my proportions are correct enough, and I don't know how to do the root at all.

Comment: Edited answer with some info about it, and a photo. Also gave you a link to my "emptyrig.fbx"